# Is it possible to create a Web Server using Azure App Services?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, webserver

I am new to Azure, that's why this kind of question is coming.
From Microsoft website, I read that : Azure App Service is a fully managed platform for creating and deploying cloud applications.
Till now, I have been using Apache HTTPD image as container on Openshift and host my static data on it. Now, I am looking to move to Azure (without using container images/kubernetes) and wondering if it is possible to create a Web Server (need not be apache only) using Azure App Services and host my static data on it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

App Service is a Platform as a Service, you'll choose the runtime (.net, node, java, etc) and publish your application into a web server. In case of chava, it can be tomcat or java se. Here's a step by step how to deploy your app to it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-java?tabs=javase&pivots=platform-linux

Comment: So, is it possible to play with the configuration of this underlying web server? And can we choose whichever web server we want here, e.g. Apace HTTPD ?

Comment: you can configure your app. The web server is managed by Azure and only java SE and Tomcat are available on App Services. If you want something different you need a VM

Comment: Ok. But wikipedia say that 'Azure apps are hosted on 'IIS 8.0' running on a custom version of Windows Server 2012'.
Doesn't that mean it comes up with IIS Web server ?

Comment: it depends on what app you'll run. IIS is for php, .net and node. For Java is TomCat or Java Se